# Rally SDK 2 - Given a story A and a story B, how can I say that B is a successor of A thanks to Javascript API?

Tags: sdk, rally

I'm using the Rally SDK 2 to manipulate user stories from Javascript in a "Custom HTML" application.

I can query a story and retrieve its attributes.
I can update some of the attributes, like the Name of the Iteration for instance.

How can I add a successor to my story?

If I understand well, I should edit the "/HierarchicalRequirement/.../Successors" of my story, but I don't understand how to do that.

Would someone have an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have an exact example you can use, but the successors (or predecessors) are 'collections'. As such, you need to 'add' to the collection. There is an explanation of some of this here: https://docs.ca.com/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2

Built into the model for the artefact are routines to handle all the details. If you want more details, then you can download the sdk-debug.js file from the Rally server. To get to it, open up the developer tools in your browser and have a look where a custom app would get the sdk.js file from. The debug variant is formatted for humans to read and a very useful source of how to do things at the low levels. The definition of Rally.data.wsapi.ModelFactory has some good tips.

One of the recommendations I make to people starting out writing custom apps, is to use the developer tools in the browser to watch the network traffic that the Rally UI makes - and then work backwards to code.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and this link. I'm using the debug tools that help a look but I was not aware of the debug SDK, I will watch it!

I now understand that I have to load the collection (as for reading) and then to add an element and save.